# Merge the duplicated lines and add "N/A" in the end

Tags: linux, sed

I have the following lines in a text file. I want to merge the duplicated lines and add "N/A" as needed at the end of the line, to have six columns on each line:

```
302C21;tSMe
S123C;1.17
302C21;2;346;SM-1-3/SM-1-4
SIEV1;tSMe
S123C;3;2225;20225
SIEV1;1;3;SM-1-1/SM-1-2;5

OUTPUT

SIEV1;tSMe;1;3;SM-1-2;5
302C21;tSMe;2;346;SM-1-3/SM-1-4;N/A
S123C;3;2225;20225;1.17;N/A
```

Comment: Does the order of the lines matter? Does the order of the fields on a line matter? If so then what rules control the ordering?

Comment: What should happen with the "N/A" if there are already six fields? What if there fewer than five fields? What if there are more than six fields?

Comment: @roaima: The sample data have five fields associated with `SIEV1`, and shows the result: just output the six columns (`SIEV1` itself, followed by `tSMe`, etc.) without adding `N/A`.

Comment: Tony: In your input data, `SIEV1` is associated with `3` followed by `SM-1-1/SM-1-2`, but, in your output data, `SIEV1` is associated with `3` followed by `SM-1-2`.  If that’s a typo; please fix it.  If it’s not a typo, please explain it.  In either case, please clarify your question.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: G-Man: my data is just an example. there is no typo. the most important is to join duplicate lines based on the first column and all lines must have the same number of columns. that is why I wanted to add N/A if the line has less column than the others,this command awk -F ";" 's != $1 || NR ==1{s=$1;if(p){print p};p=$0;next}{sub($1,"",$0);p=p""$0;}END{print p}' can do the join but it doesn't make them all with the same nuber of columns

Comment: @Tony this is relevant information. Please update your question to include it

Answer (score 5):

```sh
{   nl   -s\; -w1 -ba    | 
    sort -t\; -k2,2      | 
    sed  -e:n -e'h;$!N'  \
         -e's/^\([^;]*\(;[^;]*;\).*\)\n[^;]*\2/\1;/;tn' \
         -ex  -e:N       \
         -e's/;/;/6p;tD' \
         -e's|$|;N/A|;tN'\
         -e:D -ex -eD    |
    sort -t\; -nk1,1     |
    cut  -d\; -f2-;    
}   <in >out
```

So there's a giant pipeline. It works like this:

1. `nl` numbers all input lines and follows its line-numbers with an inserted `-s`eparator string of `;`semicolon.
2. `sort` sorts on the 2cd `;`semicolon delimited field in its input - which is your first field.
3. `sed` recursively merges input lines with identical first fields, then afterwards recursively appends the string *`;N/A`* to each line's tail until it has at least 6 fields.
4. `sort` sorts again on the first field and numerically this time - rearranging input by `nl`'s originally counted order.
5. `cut` cuts away the line numbers and delimiters originally inserted by `nl`.

#### OUTPUT:

```
302C21;tSMe;2;346;SM-1-3/SM-1-4;N/A
S123C;1.17;3;2225;20225;N/A
SIEV1;tSMe;1;3;SM-1-1/SM-1-2;5
```

These results are not identical to yours. It seems like yours are sorted in reverse, whereas these are not. Unless you clarify on what you're looking for, here you go.

P.S. I have written this in such a way that it does not matter if it is all concatenated onto a single line - and so you can just remove all newlines and any preceding backslashes to make it a one-liner.

Like so:

```sh
{ nl -s\; -w1 -ba | sort -t\; -k2,2 | sed -e:n -e'h;$!N' -e's/^\([^;]*\(;[^;]*\;).*\)\n[^;]*\2/\1;/;tn' -ex -e:N -e's/;/;/6p;tD' -e's|$|;N/A|;tN' -e:D -ex -eD | sort -t\; -nk1,1 | cut -d\; -f2-; } <in >out
```

I cannot imagine why you would want to do that though.

Comment: Mik can you please make your commands in one line?

Comment: @Tony - it already is! I said it right at the bottom - just don't copy the newlines. Or open a text editor and remove them. It's fine for a single line - just leave the newlines and trailing backslashes out.

Comment: Mik: Unfortunately it didn't work.  I want to join duplicate lines based on the first column and all lines must have the same number of columns. that is why I wanted to add N/A if the line has less column than the others,this command awk -F ";" 's != $1 || NR ==1{s=$1;if(p){print p};p=$0;next}{sub($1,"",$0);p=p""$0;}END{print p}' can do the join but it doesn't make them all with the same nuber of columns

Comment: @Tony - they do have all the same number of columns. 6. Well... If there's more than one duplicate then perhaps more than 6. Or if they came in with more than 6, then more than 6. But this only pads them to 6 - like you said in the question.